# Excel VBA sendkeys

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I wrote a macro that uses sendkeys to send F2 to a cell to activate the cell edit mode, but when run it in the editor to test the code it sends F2 in the code editor itself and not the worksheet, did I miss something?

```
Sub test()    
    call SendKeys "{f2}",true    
end sub
```

Comment: Sendkeys is 100% the same as just pressing that key on your keyboard. If you are in VBE and hit F2 that will be 100% the same as running the code, while in VBE. It's just pressing that button on your keyboard once that line executes. You will have to insure that whatever window you want to catch that keystroke is active before that SendKeys line is executed.

Comment: Referencing the first comment: Assign the macro to a keyboard shortcut or to the Ribbon so that you can run it from the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you help me how to reference to the window that should catch the keystroke, because I can't run the code from the window as I'm in the process of testing the entire code, the question I submitted is just the part which didn't work with me. please note that I write this code in the same workbook I want it to run in.

Comment: Activate the sheet first then, `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(<sheet reference>).Activate` then call SendKeys